# What does FieldGrouping ID mean in Storm?

Tags: apache-storm

This is the config:

```
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
builder.setSpout("1", new Produce(), 1);  
builder.setBolt("2", new Output(), 4).shuffleGrouping("1");
builder.setBolt("3", new Writer(), 8).fieldsGrouping("2", new Fields("ahah","bb"));

# And tuple "ahah" include{"aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd"}   
# tuple "bb" include {"ee","ff","gg","kk"}
```

There are 8 threads for 3 Bolt, and the grouping is `fieldsGrouping`, the fields include "ahah" and "bb".

And I don't know how will the 8 threads for 3 bolt work?

What does the same tuple mean? Field's `name("ahah","bb")`? or field's `content("aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","ee","ff","gg","kk")`?

Comment: I cannot follow your question. What is data and what is schema information in your examples? FieldsGrouping is similar to GROUP BY in SQL and the specified fields are similar to "column names" in SQL. Maybe this helps.

Comment: You can read more information about grouping [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_storm/apache_storm_core_concepts.htm) and about parallelism [here](http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.1/Understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-Storm-topology.html)

Answer (score 0):

> Fields grouping: The stream is partitioned by the fields specified in
>   the grouping. For example, if the stream is grouped by the "user-id"
>   field, tuples with the same "user-id" will always go to the same task,
>   but tuples with different "user-id"'s may go to different tasks.

http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.0/Concepts.html